# Unknown metrics for kafka offset metric: kafkaOffset.totalSpoutLag

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I want to get data from kafka and do some calculates,but i got some exceptions when i use storm-kafka to get data.
After the program finished 1 time freshing,there comes an exception.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eXv1.png)

I use Storm-kafka 0.9.3